# Assigning User Display Name to an Index? Powershell

Tags: powershell

Good morning/afternoon,

I have a piece of code where im trying to

- A.) Get all the Unique ID's (User logon names/profiles) found in "C:\Users"
- B.) Run `Net User ______ /domain` against them, and return the actual
  names(Display Name of the users)
- C.) Then im building an index and assigning the display name i pulled to the corresponding Index number per the order its in under C:\users.

So, when i run the code it assigned the same user to each index. If i move the input code outside the script blocks, it then outputs all the users to a complete separate list for each one like so:

Please note, the following is what happens when i move `$selection` portion out of the script block. Otherwise it would just output one index with just one name instead of multiple.

```
1:  Light, Miller
2:  Light, Miller
3:  Light, Miller

0:  Snuffy, Joe
1:  Snuffy, Joe
2:  Snuffy, Joe
3:  Snuffy, Joe

0: Account not in ADUC
1: Account not in ADUC
2: Account not in ADUC
3: Account not in ADUC
```

May i get pointed in the right direction on what i may be doing wrong, or why its acting like that?This is the code:

```
$gc = Get-ChildItem C:\users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$gcls = $gc.count
Foreach($user in $gc){

$userinfo = (net user $user /domain | Select-String "Full Name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -replace "Full Name                   ","" 2>&1 | Out-String -Stream
        if($userinfo.Length -lt 4){    

$usr = " NO DISPLAY NAME in ADUC "                   
        } else{
        if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2){
$usr = "Account not in ADUC"
           
        } else {

$usr = $userinfo

    }
}
   For($i=0; $I -lt $gcls; $i++){
    Write-host "$($i): $usr"

}

$selection = Read-Host "Enter Number"
$selection = $selection -split " "
$gc[$selection]


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop and your `Read-Host` command are nested inside your `foreach` loop, so you're printing the user information for *each* user *multiple times* and prompting for each.

Instead, you need to *collect* all information output by the `foreach` loop - i.e., all user infos - in an *array* and process that afterwards:

```
$users = Get-ChildItem C:\users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Collect all user infos in array $userinfos
$userinfos = foreach ($user in $users) {

  $userinfo = (net user $user /domain | Select-String "Full Name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -replace "Full Name                   ", "" 2>&1 | Out-String -Stream
  if ($userinfo.Length -lt 4) {    
    " NO DISPLAY NAME in ADUC "  # output
  }
  else {
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2) {
      "Account not in ADUC"    # output
    }
    else {
      $userinfo  # output
    }
  }

}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $userinfos.Count; $i++) {
  Write-Host "$($i): $($userinfos[$i])"
}

$selection = Read-Host "Enter Number"
$selection = $selection -split " "
$users[$selection]
```

Note how assigning the whole `foreach` loop to variable `$userinfos` automatically collects all output produced by the loop, and how output in the loop is produced *implicitly*, by using the string literals and the `$userinfo` variable as statements of their own, which are automatically sent to the output stream.